# Standardizing Normally Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Having the normally distributed Random variables. We can normalize it and use table values in order to calculate probability of some event.

The standardization takes formula

$$z = \frac{ X - \text{expected value} }{ \text{variance}}$$

It is told that by doing this, we are forcing our variable $X$ to have expected value $0$ and variance $1$. However why is that? Why by doing steps above we force the distribution to behave like that?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Compute the mean and variance of $z.$ What do you get? Also, it should be divided by the square root of the variance (the standard deviation), not the variance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your formula to standardize a normal random variable is not correct.

The formula should be $$Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma},$$ where $\sigma$ is the **standard deviation**, not the variance, which is $\sigma^2$.

Recall that for $X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the probability density function is $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}.$$  Then $Z = (X-\mu)/\sigma$ has PDF $$f_Z(z) = f_X(\sigma z + \mu) \left|\frac{d}{dz}[\sigma z + \mu] \right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-(\sigma z + \mu - \mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}.$$  Therefore $Z$ has mean $0$ and variance $1$; i.e., it is standard normal.

Comment: Hello @heropup can you tell me where you took the last formula with the derivative d/dz please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I hope this can solve your doubt: $$ P(Z=z) = P(X=x)$$ therefore $$ f_Z(z)dz = f_X(\sigma z + \mu) dx $$ where: $$ dx = \frac{d}{dz}(\sigma z +u)dz$$

Comment: Hello @MatteoMenghini thank you very much for your precious comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu$ be the mean, that is $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ be the variance, that is $\operatorname{Var}{X}=\sigma^2$.

Notice that $$z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$

There is a mistake in your standardization, we do not divide by the variance but the standard deviation.

$$\mathbb{E}[Z]=\frac{1}{\sigma}(\mathbb{E}[X]-\mu)$$

$$\operatorname{Var}[Z]=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\operatorname{Var}[X-\mu])$$

Are you able to complete the proof?

Remark: You might also want to prove perhaps using mgf that $Z$ is a normal distribution too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the same result of @heropup and @MatteoMenghini, starting from the cumulative distribution functions.

$$
\begin{equation}
Z := \frac{X-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}
\end{equation}
$$

The transformation is monotonically increasing, since $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}\right)=1/\sigma_x>0$, then we have that

$$
\begin{align}
F_z(z) &= P(Z\leq z) \stackrel{\mathscr{S}}{=} P\left(\frac{X-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}\leq z\right)
\\&=
P(X \leq \sigma_x z + \mu_x) \stackrel{\mathscr{S}}{=} P(X \leq x)
\\&=
F_x(x)
\end{align}
$$

substituting

$$
F_z(z) \stackrel{\mathscr{S}}{=} F_x(\sigma_x z + \mu_x) \label{Fz}
$$

differentiating

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dz} F_z(z) &= \frac{d}{dz} F_x(\sigma_x z + \mu_x)
\\
f_z(z) &= \sigma_x f_x(\sigma_x z + \mu_x)
\\
f_z(z) &= \sigma_x f_x(x) \label{fz}
\end{align}
$$